# Angular function in controller doesn't return a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am having difficulty with having a function inside a controller in angular return a value to a variable.

Here is the function:

```
var getUser = function(user_id, key) { 
    var user;

    var request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/torteez/api/user/' + user_id,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    $http(request)
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            if(key === 'all') {
                user = response;
            } else {
                user = response.data[0][key];
            }
        }, function errorCallback(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    return user;
};
```

And here is the variable where the user detail should be returned to:

```
var username = getUser(row['user_id'], 'username');
```

Please, tell where the problem is.

Comment: `$(http)` is asynchronous.

Comment: You need to look up a tutorial or sample, $http is async and doesn't return until the async call completes, so user will not be anything.  You need to set something inside your callback to use it.

Comment: The request is made async, so you will have to add a callback to your function...

Comment: getUser method makes an asynchronous request but it will return the variable user before the REST api call is complete.

Comment: I worked around a solution by creating a global variable $scope.firstname = '': and assigning it the value inside the function